# How to lock concurrent access to a shared webservice from multiple webservers?

Tags: proxy, queue, concurrency, web-services

Our production environment consists in n Apache web servers accessed by browsers via a frontal load balancer. Very typical. 99% of our HTTP requests are gracefully handled by this parallelized architecture with no problem.

Unfortunately, 1% of the requests handled by Apache need to access to a tier SOAP webservice, on a foreign server, which is **absolutely unable to handle concurrency**, resulting in many critical errors.

I'm looking for a way to canalise those SOAP requests through a sort of proxy, able to queue and lock synchronously the requests to the foreign server.

Do standard proxies like Pound, Nginx, Squid or Varnish implement such queues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon has a service that you could use. It's called Simple Queue Service. http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/

You can use this to queue jobs and pick them off the queue one at a time.

> When a message is received, it becomes “locked” while being processed.
>   This keeps other computers from processing the message simultaneously.
>   If the message processing fails, the lock will expire and the message
>   will be available again. In the case where the application needs more
>   time for processing, the “lock” timeout can be changed dynamically via
>   the ChangeMessageVisibility operation.

There are number of alternatives that could suit your use case:

- Redis - http://redis.io/topics/transactions
- Rabiitmq - http://www.rabbitmq.com/
- Elasticmq - https://github.com/adamw/elasticmq
- Mongodb - http://www.mattinsler.com/post/26536863600/why-and-how-i-replaced-amazon-sqs-with-mongodb

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clues. Redis seems quite an option since we also make abundant use of shared memory. Could be one stone two birds.

Answer (score 0):

Redis may be a solution to this kind of problem. As it [handles atomic operations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/RedisLocks).